# How to convert php string with backslashes to json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to produce this JSON array using php

```
{"to": "/topics/foo-bar"}
```

but if i use this code :

```
$topic = "/topics/foo-bar";
    $g_topic= array(
                'to' => $topic
            );
    echo json_encode($g_topic );
```

it is returning this

> {"to": "/topics/foo-bar"}

I have tried `stripslashes()`, `addslashes()`, but none of the methods worked

Comment: I suppose you didn't check the php manual http://php.net/json_encode http://3v4l.org/GILQ0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is right there in [the manual for the json_encode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo json_encode($g_topic, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

will yield:

```
{"to": "/topics/foo-bar"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo it out like this.

```
$topic = "/topics/foo-bar";
$g_topic= array(
            'to' => $topic
        );
echo json_encode($g_topic, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), "\n";
```